# JavaFx application is not compiling when running it from the CMD

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I wrote a game built on `JavaFX` using Eclipse. When running the game from Eclipse, it runs perfectly. However, when I try and run it from the `CMD`, I get compile errors like:

```
Game.java:146: error: ';' expected
                close.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
                                     ^
Game.java:146: error: <identifier> expected
                close.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
                                                   ^
Game.java:146: error: ';' expected
                close.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
                                                     ^
Game.java:150: error: <identifier> expected
                StartLayout.setId("pane");
```

Could this be a problem with the `JavaFX` installation? ideas?

Comment: Place full javac command with you try to compile

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean. I'm trying to run javac *.java and it's like not recognizing JavaFX code

Comment: Lambda expressions (e -> window.close()) require java 8 (javac 1.8+ to compile). From your comment on the answer, it seems that you are using javac 1.7.

Comment: how do you think I can fix that? I already downloaded the latest version of JDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your java version? If u wanna use lambda expression, then you need java 8. Open cmd and check ur java version. Write this on cmd line:

```
java -version
```

On Eclipse Windows - Preferences - Java - Installed Jre.

Comment: it gives me javac 1.7.0_67 but the main one is java version "1.8.0_131"

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem. I apparently once installed some Java packages from a coursera course on Data structures which had a previous version of javac. I edited the path and everything works out.

Comment: Open cmd line. Copy this: rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables. Then envoriment variables will be open. Check JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME variable path.